# How do I get r_squared from loss minimization with constraints using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, regression

Performed a regression with numpy and scipy using loss minimization with constraints. Here is an example:

y_values is a vector with numObservations values

x_matrix_trans is the x matrix

we want to solve y = Xc with a constraint such that some of the coefficients multiplied by some input weights have to sum to 0.

```
    def constraint1(x):
        res = 0
        for i in range (0, NUM_WEIGHTS):
            res = res + x[CONST_VAL + i] * weights[CONST_VAL + i]
        return res

    def loss(x):
        return np.sum(np.square((np.dot(x, x_matrix_trans) - y_values)))

    cons = ({'type': 'eq',
             'fun' : constraint1})

    x0 = np.zeros(x_matrix_trans.shape[0])        
    res = minimize(loss, x0, method='SLSQP',constraints=cons, options={'disp': True, 'maxiter' : 1000, 'ftol' : 1e-07}) 
    print(res.x)
```

My regression produced the correct values in res.x but I also needed to calculate the r_squared and the adjusted r_squared. I tried to calculate the r_squared but they turned out incorrect.

Here is how I attempted to calculate the r_squared:

```
    ymeas = y_values
    yfit = np.dot(res.x, x_matrix_trans)
    ss_res = np.sum((ymeas - yfit) ** 2)
    ss_tot = np.var(ymeas) * len(ymeas)
    rsq = 1 - ss_res / ss_tot
```

Here is how I attempted to calculate the adjusted r_squared:

```
    adjRsq = 0.0
    if ((num_coefficients - num_observations - 1) != 0):
        adjRsq = rsq - (1-rsq)*(num_coefficients - 1)/( num_observations -num_coefficients - 1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can say in what sense your results are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out my answer was correct all along. With the exception of adjusted r_square which according to wikipedia should be

```
adjRsq = rsq - (1-rsq)*(num_coeff)/(num_observations-num_coeff-1)
```

and not

```
adjRsq = rsq - (1-rsq)*(num_coeff - 1)/(num_observations-num_coeff-1)
```